# STM32 F334R8 UART Category doesnt shown

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, nextion

Im working on a project with Nextion HMI and STM32 F334R8.  When I try to send string to Nextion with STM, UART doest shown in the category section in CubeIDE(This board has 3 USARTs but no UARTs). Is there a mistake Im making or my STM doest normally have any UART(if thats possible)?
Where can I select UART? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fpuU.png)

Comment: A USART is even better. It can be configured to do anything a UART can do, plus some more things.

Comment: Also the STM32 HAL UART drivers work if passed a USART instance, so if you have already written the code with the UART driver you only have to change one definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `USART` instead, in setting parameters choose `Mode: Asynchronous` (it will be the same as `UART`).